# XPages Create Links from Array in Computed Field

Tags: xpages, computed-field

I put a computed filed in a XPages and then i created value via this code below. Every line has its own link but before i complete this code i am trying to learn how to remove the comma at the beginning of line. There must be another way to do this. Should i use one of other design elements like repeat control?

```xml
<xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1" style="font-size:8pt">
  <xp:this.value>
  <![CDATA[#{javascript:{ var links = ["A1","A2","A3","","A444",""];
for (i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
    var strText = arr1[i];
    if (strText=="") {
      strText = "There is no value";
    }
    links[i] =  "<a href="+ arr1[i] + "target=\"_blank\">"+strText+"</a><br>";
  }
  return links;}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

[image: How to remove COMMA in array]

Any suggestion is appreciated, 
Cumhur Ata

Comment: You have an extra set of {}. Is that a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a repeat control for this rather than a Computed Field doing an SSJS loop to build a string of HTML. It will be easier to read, easier to avoid coding errors, easier to troubleshoot, easier to support and easier to extend.

Comment: It's copy/paste mistake, sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cumhur, as Paul pointed, a repeat loop is the best for such a purpose.

For this specific case, you return an array as a value. Imploding the array to a string will solve your issue.

```
return @Implode(links,"\n");
```

Also, instead of adding `<br>` on every elements, you can use it as a separator.

```
return @Implode(links,"<br/>");
```

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend you use a Repeat Control.  If you do to get your desired results it might look something like this:

```xml
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="rowData">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var links = ["A1","A2","A3","","A444",""]
return links;}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:link escape="true" value="#{rowData}" id="link1" target="_blank">
    <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:var temp:string = rowData;
if (temp.length == 0) {
    return "There is no value";
} else {
    return rowData;
}}]]></xp:this.text>
    </xp:link>
    <br/>
</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: Thank you Ericand and David..
I will change the code and will use Repeat Control as you mentioned.